# How to add +1 to the value of array after specific position in php

Tags: php, arrays

can any one explain how to add +1 to the value of array after the specific position element in php.

actually i have to increment the value of all key when on specific postion will get

Comment: Start with writing some code. And read [mcve]

Comment: Look at your question and then say "Could I answer this question if someone ELSE asked this question, who was not looking over my shoulder"

Comment: `$array[$specific_position + 1]++` :) and to be more specific I think you may use array_slice() and foreach after slicing from specific position